# How to visualize articulation with fuerte

Tags: rviz, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying out the nice articulation package.
However, the `articulation_rviz_plugin` does not exist anymore and most of the tutorials require the plugin. Having said that it's always useful to have a visualization. The manifest files state:

```
<!-- does not work in fuerte
<depend package="articulation_rviz_plugin"/>
-->
```

So, is there a way to visualize the results of the articulation package anyway, and if not, what is the best way to create a visualization by hand?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53793/how-to-visualize-articulation-with-fuerte/) by [jon_ross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4093/jon_ross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I spoke to one of the developers. Currently there is no visualization in fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [jon_ross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4093/jon_ross/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0